# How to send static file link as variable in `include` tag in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose I have a `base.html` and `home.html`. The `base.html` file has:

```
{% include 'home.html' with thelink='hard/coded/link' %}
```

And `home.html` contains:

```
The link of static file is : {{ thelink }}
```

This works well so far. But now, I want to do this:

`base.html`:

```
{% load static %}
{% include 'home.html' with thelink={% static 'link' %} %}
```

I know this will not work. So how do I send a variable with static files references in the `include` tag?

Comment: Static tag just appends your STATIC_ROOT path to your link, try passing `{% include 'home.html' with thelink='{{thelink}}' %}` and in the template `home.html` put `{% static '{{thelink}}' %}` wherever you want.

Comment: I have tried this, but `thelink` variable has only the string '{{thelink}}` in it. So variable referencing with `{{ var_name }}` cannot be done inside `{% %}`. That is the problem.

Comment: `src="{% static '' %}<space>{{ thelink }}"` should not contain space inbetween as it is a url. So, I have to assign the file location in variable `thelink` from `base.html` and then get the static url from `home.html`. Nice trick!! Another thing, can you tell be the difference between `src="{% static '' %}{{ thelink }}"` and `src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ thelink }}"`?

Comment: `src="{% static '' %}{{ thelink }}"` the `{% static '' %}` will bring your STATIC_ROOT_PATH which is configured in `settings.py`. Basically STATIC_ROOT is tells where your collected static files are(points to directory). Whenever you call `python manage.py collectstatic` all the static files gets collected in the STATIC_ROOT directory so the STATIC_ROOT just points to the path where your collected static files lies.  The `src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ thelink }}"` is also similar to this only. In both cased both strings are just getting appended.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing from the comments section:

In `base.html`

```
{% include 'home.html' with thelink='hard/coded/link without STATIC_URL' %}
```

In `home.html` (I have used the `src=` for example)

```
src="{% static '' %}{{thelink}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Django template language supports your use case.

You can assign the result of `static` to a template variable using `as`.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static

This should work

```
{% load static %}
{% static 'link' as m_link %}
{% include 'home.html' with thelink=m_link %}
```